# Failing to catch Firebase authentication error for duplicate emails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase v10 for authentication on my React web app. I am able to create a user and log in, thus authentication is working, however, if a new user tries to enter an email which already exists in my database, the error sent back from Firebase is not being caught in my code (although firebase is sending back an error in console and it is not adding the duplicate user to the database as intended).

I am using an Authentication context JavaScript file, which calls the Firebase create user method, and I am referencing the context in a sign up page.

My context code

```
const AuthContext = createContext()

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {

    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    function signup(email, password) {
        methods.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(cred =>{
            if (cred !== undefined){
                let userType;
            if (email.substring(email.indexOf('@') + 1) === "sun.ac.za"){
                userType = "student";
            }
            else{
                userType = "company";
            }
            let data = {
                email: cred.user.email,
                type: userType
            };
            setDoc(doc(users, cred.user.uid), data);
            }            
          }       
          )
    }
```

My sign in page's function for handling the form submit

```
 async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(emailRef.current.value))) {
            return setError("Please enter a valid email address.");
        }

        if (passwordRef.current.value.length < 6) {
            return setError("Please enter a password of at least 6 characters.");
        }

        if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
            return setError("Passwords do not match.");
        }


        try {
            setError("")
            setLoading(true)
            await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
        } catch (e) {
                return setError("Cannot create an account.");
            }
            setLoading(false);
            navigate('/');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the [Promises chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining) in the `signup` function, as follows:

```
export function AuthProvider({ children }) {

    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    function signup(email, password) {
       return methods.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(cred =>{
            if (cred !== undefined){
                let userType;
            if (email.substring(email.indexOf('@') + 1) === "sun.ac.za"){
                userType = "student";
            }
            else{
                userType = "company";
            }
            let data = {
                email: cred.user.email,
                type: userType
            };
            return setDoc(doc(users, cred.user.uid), data);
            }            
          }       
          )
    }
```

Comment: Since `setDoc` is asynchronous too, the code needs a return in front of `setDoc(doc(users, cred.user.uid), data);` too.

Comment: Oh yes, good catch @FrankvanPuffelen! Indeed we need to return the **entire** Promises chain. Thx

Comment: Thanks everyone, you were correct in that a return statement is required, however I am still unable to catch the duplicate email error. I have also removed the last promise to check if was causing the problem, but it still persists without it.

Comment: "I am still unable to catch the duplicate email error" What do you exactly mean? The error is not propagated to the calling function (`handleSubmit`)? Or you do get the error in `handleSubmit` but you cannot identify which type of error it is?